# net.vb only numbers and validation message

Tags: vb.net

In to my Windows App Form, I have two text boxes and I would like the User to give me only Numbers And if the user gives me letters like for example (hello) when he executes the button I would like to inform the user through a window Validation message " Please enter numerical values ". How can I write it through Basic code?

Comment: Handle the `Validating` event to validate controls. There are loads of examples around about validating numerical input. You need to make an effort before posting here and show us what you have tried and explain how it didn't work. If you haven't even searched for a solution then it's too soon to be asking here.

Comment: How about a NumericUpDown control instead of a TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply use the function `IsNumeric()` to achieve it.

Look at the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) And IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then
    Else
        MsgBox("Please input numbers only!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Output of the form:

[image: Output]

TextBox2 verification:

[image: Output for TextBox2]

Enjoy!

Comment: The .TryParse methods available in .net improve performance and provide you with a typed variable for further computation. You probably want AndAlso since there is no point in verifying the second tb if the first fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can check text box value with help of regex or isnumeric function. you can validate input at leave event of textbox and use error provider control to show warning message.

```
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
        If Not Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "\d+") Then
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "only numerics are allowed")
        Else
            ErrorProvider1.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The question was asked for the events of clicking a button. Condition: *when he executes the button I would like to inform the user through*...